# rxJava + Retrofit2 Получить актуальные данные

Tags: android, json, api, rxjava2

Делаю запрос

```
  @SuppressLint("CheckResult")
    private Observable<Exchange> kursRequest(){
        String base = exchange.getBase();
        String symbols=symbolsWaluta;
   return request(base,symbols);

    }

    private Observable<Exchange> request(String nameWaluta, String nameWaluta2){
       return  Network.getService().getDara(nameWaluta,nameWaluta2)
                      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.single())
                      .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
        }
```

Подписываюсь

```
@SuppressLint("CheckResult")
    public String getKurs() {
     kursRequest()
        .subscribe
        (s->kurs=s.getRates().get(symbolsWaluta).toString()) ;
     return kurs;
    }
```

Получаю результат-

> kurs

НО получаю старый,то есть обновляется ,тогда когда делаю повторный запрос. То есть,если `kurs==0`,то при 1 запросе так и останется `kurs==0`, обновится только при 2 запросе. Как исправить,что бы сразу получать результат?

Comment: интересный вопрос

Comment: Вы имеете в виду, что ожидаете выброса нового значения как только на сервере изменится цена? Если да, то это надо совсем иначе делать - коннектится к северу через сокеты (сервер должен предоставить такую возможность). Ну или вручную постоянно перезапускать запрос.